# Kendo datepicker is dispalying date in long format with time how to avoid it

Tags: knockout-2.0

This is code I am using can be seen by clicking the this link
http://jsfiddle.net/fGq5w/1/
On click of the button , I change the date. But the time is also displayed.
How to display one date alone when i click the button.

**HTML CODE**

```
       <input id="myDatePicker" data-bind="value: currentDate" />

        <h2>Current Date is:<strong data-bind="text: currentDate"></strong></h2>

      <input type='button' value='change Date' onclick='changeDate();return false;'  />
```

**Javascript**

```
var vm = {
    currentDate: ko.observable()   
};


$(function(){

ko.applyBindings(vm);

$("#myDatePicker").kendoDatePicker();

});

function changeDate()
{
 alert('ok');
 vm.currentDate(new Date(2014,1,1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Kendo question. Just format the date with kendo's date formatting tools:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting

eg...

```
vm.currentDate(kendo.toString(new Date(2013,0,1), "MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Code with additional functionality to pre-fill the date TextBox.

  var vm = {
        currentDate: ko.observable(kendo.toString(new Date(),'MM/dd/yyyy'))   
    };


$(function(){

    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $("#myDatePicker").kendoDatePicker();

});

    enter code here

function changeDate()
{
  alert('ok');
  vm.currentDate(kendo.toString(new Date(2014,1,1),'MM/dd/yyyy'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Knockout 3.3.0, you can create an extension to handle the formatting since calling a function manually isn't terribly ideal:

*(In the snipper below I'm using moment.js to parse the date, but you could use kendo's date parser - although it doesn't work with certain ISO formatted dates)*

```
ko.extenders.stripTime = function (target) {
    var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target,
        write: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                target(moment(value).format(shell.getDateFormatString()));
            }
            else {
                target(value);
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    result(target());

    return result;
};
```

In your client-side viewmodel, apply the extension to your observable:

```
self.SomeDateProperty = ko.observable().extend({ stripTime: null });
```

I recommend not using ko.toJS when you try to get a javascript object from your observables when using kendo datepicker - Instead, use ko.mapping (you need to download the JS library separately).

```
var someJavascriptObject = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
```